# enable ssl for openstack

Tags: apache, ssl, openstack

I do not know if here where I have to put my question or not. I really need help. it's been three days i'm trying to configure SSL in openstack with httpd but i fail, i've followed redhat documentation  [Configuring Secured Deployment (HTTPS)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/3/html/Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/Configuring_Secured_Deployment_HTTPS.html)  with my own setup but when i restart httpd service i get some errors below : 
[httpd status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly47d.png)

[openstack-dashboard.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOl8.png)

Comment: What tools did you use to install openstack (tripleO, Ansible-Openstack) this will go a long way towards helping you solve this problem.

Comment: thanks for responding , i actually fixed the probleme, i had to enable firewall and allow https traffic